# Ask for a regex for re.sub in python

Tags: python

I have some string like these, there will be 0 or more whitespace before or after `=`, and there will be 0 or 1 `### comment` at the end of the string.

```
log_File = a.log   ### the path for log
log_level = 10
```

Now I want to replace the string on the right of `=`. for example, set them to as below:

```
log_File = b.log   ### the path for log
log_level = 40 

import re
s="log_File = a.log   ### the path for log"
re.sub("(?<=\s)\w+\S+",'Hello",s)
```

The above code replaces all the strings after = to Hello, I don't want to replace the strings after `###`, how can I implement this.

Comment: Can you clarify the formatting requirements? Writing a good regex is heavily dependent on what you know about the file format. Will there always be exactly one string on the right side of the equals sign? Will there sometimes be multiple strings, or no strings? If there are numbers, do you want them replaced as well? More specificity would be very helpful. Or a few more test cases with example outputs, at least.

Comment: Could you confirm that your intent is to make such substitutions inside a Python code , please ?

Comment: You may be interested by the EDIT I posted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<!#)=(.*?)(?=\s*#|$)', r'= Hello', s, 1)
'log_File = Hello   ### the path for log'
```

Without using regular expression (Inbar Rose's version modified)

```
def replace_value(s, new):
    content, sep1, comment = s.partition('#')
    key, sep2, value = content.partition('=')
    if sep2: content = key + sep2 + new
    return content + sep1 + comment

assert replace_value('log_File = b', ' Hello') == 'log_File = Hello'
assert replace_value('#log_File = b', ' Hello') == '#log_File = b'
assert replace_value('#This is comment', ' Hello') == '#This is comment'
assert replace_value('log_File = b # hello', ' Hello') == 'log_File = Hello# hello'
```

Comment: This is not a good solution, sorry, there are too many ways it can go wrong... for instance: The string: `'var = (tuple, value) # comment'` yeilds: `'var = (tuple, Hello # comment'`

Comment: @InbarRose, I added another solution.

Comment: And the new solution you added still is not good, `'var = (tuple, value) # comment'` yields `'var = (tuple, value) # comment'` there is no change.

Comment: @InbarRose, where did you come up with the tuple thing?

Comment: @perreal It is *obvious* that the OP is using this regex substitution on Python code, and not all code is `X = Y` so when designing a regular expression to catch non-comment values after an assignment (`=`) the regex needs to be more complex than just "the first non-white-space"

Comment: How is it obvious. `log_File = a.log ` is not a valid Pyhton expression, is it?

Comment: @InbarRose, How about `re.sub(r'(?<!#)=(.*?)(#|$)', r'= Hello', s)`?

Comment: no it is not. `log_File = "a.log"` is though. I mean with quotes.

Comment: @falsetru better, but now you are removing the `#`: `re.sub(r'(?<!#)=(.*?)(#|$)', r'= Hello', s)` yeilds `'var = Hello comment'`

Comment: @InbarRose, How about `re.sub(r'(?<!#)=(.*?)(?=#|$)', r'= Hello', s)`? (Sorry for bothering you)

Comment: @perreal are you serious? a.log could be an attribute/property/method/function that is being assigned to the variable `log_File` and regardless of Python or not Python, not all code in different languages also contain whitespace in between arguments such as `a = range(1, 10)`

Comment: @InbarRose, I'm serious, you cannot make assumptions about a language and try to parse it based on the given example. And log_file = a.log is more likely referring to a filename.

Comment: I think  **re.sub(r'(?<!#)=(.*?)(?=#|$)', r'= Hello', s)** is ok

Comment: @jim_wan2, That will remove spaces between `Hello` and `#`.

Comment: @falsetru @jim_wan2 The results of the **regex** and the **function** of the _falsetru_ 's answer are **False,True** on the assignement ``y = b.log ### x = a.log``, are **True,False** on ``d['AB#12'] = 45``, and **False,False** on ``a = 'lulu#88'``

Comment: @eyquem, Thank you for comment. I don't have idea for those cases with simple code. Could you provide more robust solution? (Sorry for my poor English, too. )

Comment: This works：  `re.sub(r"(?<==)(\s*)(.*?)(?=\s*(#{3}|$))",r"\1Hello",s)`

Answer (score -2):

I don't see where's the problem.

What about the following code ?

```
import re

pat = '(=\s*).+?(?=\s*(#|$))'
rgx = re.compile(pat,re.MULTILINE)

su = '''log_File = a.log   ### the path for log   
log_File = a.log   
log_File = a.log'''

print su
print
print rgx.sub('\\1Hello',su)
```

.

#### EDIT

.

I have seen where's the problem !

As I wrote it, I don't think that the problem can be simply solved by only regex or a relatively simple function, because changing the right-part of an assignement (attribute called **value** in the AST node of an assignement) without touching the possible comment requires a syntactic analyze to determine what is the left-part of an assignement (attribute called **targets** in an AST node of an assignement), what is the right-part and what is the possible comment in a line. And even if a line isn't an assignement instruction, a syntactic analyze is required to determine it.

For such a task there's only the module `ast`, which *helps Python applications to process trees of the Python abstract syntax grammar*, that can provide the tools to achieve the goal, in my opinion.

Here's the code I succeeded to write on this idea:

```
import re,ast       
from sys import exit

su = '''# it's nothing
import re
def funcg(a,b):\r
    print a*b + 900
x = "abc#ghi"\t\t# comment
k = 103
dico["abc#12"] = [(x,x//3==0) for x in xrange(25) if x !=12]
dico["ABC#12"] = 45   # comment
a = 'lulu#88'
dico["mu=$*"] = 'mouth#30'  #ohoh
log_File = a.log
y = b.log ### x = a.log  
'''

print su

def subst_assign_val_in_line(line,b0,repl):
    assert(isinstance(b0,ast.AST))
    coloffset = b0.value.col_offset
    VA = line[coloffset:]
    try:
        yy = compile(VA+'\n',"-expr-",'eval')
    except: # because of a bug of ast in computing VA
        coloffset = coloffset - 1
        VA = line[coloffset:]
        yy = compile(VA+'\n',"-expr-",'eval')

    gen = ((i,c) for i,c in enumerate(VA) if c=='#')
    for i,c in gen:
        VAshort = VA[0:i] # <== cuts in front of a # character
        try:
            yyi = compile(VAshort+'\n',"-exprshort-",'eval')
        except:
            pass
        else:
            if yy==yyi:
                return (line[0:coloffset] + repl + ' ' +
                        line[coloffset+i:])
                break
            else:
                print 'VA = line[%d:]' % coloffset
                print 'VA :  %r' % VA
                print '  yy != yyi  on:'
                print 'VAshort : %r' % VAshort
                raw_input('  **** UNIMAGINABLE CASE ***')

    else:
        return line[0:coloffset] + repl
            


def subst_assigns_vals_in_text(text,repl,
                               rgx = re.compile('\A([ \t]*)(.*)')):

    def yi(text):
        for line in text.splitlines():
            head,line = rgx.search(line).groups()
            try:
                body = ast.parse(line,'line','exec').body
            except:
                yield head + line
            else:   
                if isinstance(body,list):
                    if len(body)==0:
                        yield head + line
                    elif len(body)==1:
                        if type(body[0])==ast.Assign:
                            yield head + subst_assign_val_in_line(line,
                                                                  body[0],
                                                                  repl)
                        else:
                            yield head + line
                    else:
                        print "list ast.parse(line,'line','exec').body has more than 1 element"
                        print body
                        exit()
                else:
                    print "ast.parse(line,'line','exec').body is not a list"
                    print body
                    exit()

    return '\n'.join(yi(text))

print subst_assigns_vals_in_text(su,repl='Hello')
```

In fact, I wrote it accompanied with instructions `print` and the help of a personnal programm to display an AST tree in a readable manner (for me).
Here after is the code with instructions `print` only, to follow the process:

```
import re,ast       
from sys import exit

su = '''# it's nothing
import re
def funcg(a,b):\r
    print a*b + 900
x = "abc#ghi"\t\t# comment
k = 103
dico["abc#12"] = [(x,x//3==0) for x in xrange(25) if x !=12]
dico["ABC#12"] = 45   # comment
a = 'lulu#88'
dico["mu=$*"] = 'mouth#30'  #ohoh
log_File = a.log
y = b.log ### x = a.log  
'''

print su
print '#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-'

def subst_assign_val_in_line(line,b0,repl):
    assert(isinstance(b0,ast.AST))
    print '\n%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\nline :  %r' % line
    print '\nb0 == body[0]: ',b0
    print '\nb0.value: ',b0.value
    print '\nb0.value.col_offset==',b0.value.col_offset
    coloffset = b0.value.col_offset
    VA = line[coloffset:]
    try:
        yy = compile(VA+'\n',"-expr-",'eval')
    except: # because of a bug of ast in computing VA
        coloffset = coloffset - 1
        VA = line[coloffset:]
        yy = compile(VA+'\n',"-expr-",'eval')
    print 'VA = line[%d:]' % coloffset
    print 'VA :  %r' % VA
    print ("yy = compile(VA+'\\n',\"-expr-\",'eval')\n"
           'yy =='),yy
    gen = ((i,c) for i,c in enumerate(VA) if c=='#')
    deb = ("mwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmw\n"
           "    mwmwmwm '#' in VA  mwmwmwm\n")
    for i,c in gen:
        print '%si == %d   VA[%d] == %r' % (deb,i,i,c)
        deb = ''
        VAshort = VA[0:i] # <== cuts in front of a # character
        print '  VAshort = VA[0:%d] == %r' % (i,VAshort)
        try:
            yyi = compile(VAshort+'\n',"-exprshort-",'eval')
        except:
            print "  compile(%r+'\\n',\"-exprshort-\",'eval') gives error" % VAshort
        else:
            print ("  yyi = compile(VAshort+'\\n',\"-exprshort-\",'eval')\n"
                   '  yyi =='),yy
            if yy==yyi:
                print '  yy==yyi   Real value of assignement found'
                print "mwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmwmw"
                return (line[0:coloffset] + repl + ' ' +
                        line[coloffset+i:])
                break
            else:
                print 'VA = line[%d:]' % coloffset
                print 'VA :  %r' % VA
                print '  yy != yyi  on:'
                print 'VAshort : %r' % VAshort
                raw_input('  **** UNIMAGINABLE CASE ***')
    else:
        return line[0:coloffset] + repl
            

def subst_assigns_vals_in_text(text,repl,
                               rgx = re.compile('\A([ \t]*)(.*)')):

    def yi(text):
        for line in text.splitlines():
            raw_input('\n\npause')
            origline = line
            head,line = rgx.search(line).groups()
            print ('#########################################\n'
                   '#########################################\n'
                   'line     : %r\n'
                   'cut line : %r' % (origline,line))
            try:
                body = ast.parse(line,'line','exec').body
            except:
                yield head + line
            else:
                if isinstance(body,list):
                    if len(body)==0:
                        yield head + line
                    elif len(body)==1:
                        if type(body[0])==ast.Assign:
                            yield head + subst_assign_val_in_line(line,
                                                                  body[0],
                                                                  repl)
                        else:
                            yield head + line
                    else:
                        print "list ast.parse(line,'line','exec').body has more than 1 element"
                        print body
                        exit()
                else:
                    print "ast.parse(line,'line','exec').body is not a list"
                    print body
                    exit()

    #in place of return '\n'.join(yi(text)) , to print the output
    def returning(text):
        for output in yi(text):
            print 'output   : %r' % output
            yield output

    return '\n'.join(returning(text))
                        

print '\n\n\n%s' % subst_assigns_vals_in_text(su,repl='Hello')
```

I don't give explanations because it would be too long to explain the structure of the AST tree of a code created by `ast.parse()`. I xwill give some lights on my code if asked

**NB** there's a bug in the functionning of `ast.parse()` when it gives the line and column at which begins certain nodes, so I was obliged to correct that byadditional lines of instructions.
For example, it gives a false result on a list comprehension.

Comment: If `su` is `log_File = a.log   ### log_File = b.log`, your code yield `log_File = Hello   ### log_File = Hello`. (Comment changed)

Comment: @falsetru Well it's easy to correct this precise flaw: ``pat = '(=\s*).+?(\s*(#.*$|$))`` and ``rgx.sub('\\1Hello\\2',su)``. But now it's ``a = 'lulu#2'`` which is changed into ``a = Hello#2'``. I don't think that we can success with regex. It isn't a problem of regex power, it is a problem of coder power: we will never succeed to think to all the kinds of instructions that will give tricky effects (excuse my poor english, I think you undertsand what I mean). We must seek for other strategy than just using a regex.